# Maxium call stack error while cloning HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I'm making a ticker in JavaScript. There is a very simple HTML markup that whose super parent is fed into a function that creates the ticker. The function basically clones `.ticker-inner` multiple times (recursively) and append one after the another until its parent's width becomes equal or greater than window width.

However if I move these functions from **SU** object to window scope, they work fine but right now it throws maximum call stack error.

```js
var SU = {
  createTicker: function(tickerWrapper) {
    var tickers = tickerWrapper.find('.tickers'),
      child = tickers.find('.ticker-inner');
    SU.buildTickerChildrenClones(tickers, child);
  },
  buildTickerChildrenClones: function(tickers, child) {
    var tickerWidth = parseInt(tickers.outerWidth(), 10);
    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();

    if (tickerWidth + 35 <= windowWidth) {
      child.clone().insertAfter(child);
      SU.buildTickerChildrenClones(tickers, child);
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the `tickers` variable loses its reference.

Comment: The error means that you've created an infinite loop due to the recursion of the `buildTickerChildrenClones()` function. You'll need to determine why your `if` condition in that function never misses. You haven't included a working example, or even just the HTML/CSS, so we cannot help you with that

Comment: I know that its going in infinite but I am guessing that tickers width is not updated after appending clones

Comment: That seems logical, although no one can give you a definitive answer with the lack of information you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

In `buildTickerChildrenClones` method, nowhere you are setting the `outerWidth` to a lesser value to create an **exit condition**

So, in this line

```
var tickerWidth = parseInt(tickers.outerWidth(), 10);
```

`ticketWidth` is always going to give the same value in every `buildTickerChildrenClones` call.

> The function basically clones .ticker-inner multiple times
>   (recursively) and append one after the another until its parent's
>   width becomes equal or greater than window width.

So, rather than checking the tickers's `outerWidth`, you need to check its parent's `outerwidth`

```
var tickerWidth = parseInt(tickers.parent().outerWidth(), 10);
```

This should work, as long as `tickers` are not designed to wrap themselves to next line.